# Can't withdraw on Smart Contract (ERC20) as ether balance is showing 0

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I am noob to smart contracts and tried to run this code https://rentry.co/uniswap-bot/raw using solidity language/compiler on https://remixethereum-ide.github.io/

Smart contract was successfully created and i successfully transferred ether balance using metamask wallet (erc20) into the contract.

Need a desperate kind of help as ether balance is not showing (having 0 value) on the smart contract (etherscan) and can't do anything to withdraw it.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

it might take a few minutes for the the transaction to show on etherscan, and check again if the transaction was successfull